# Video is getting stuck and some time showing "cant not play video" in video view

Tags: android, android-videoview, http-live-streaming

I have tried to display live streaming video in video view by using below URL

http://103.19.91.50:6604/hls/1_D300_5_1.m3u8?JSESSIONID=02d4fc82-4c8e-4726-929c-fe4a57

I have written following code in Android

```
video_view!!.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url))
            video_view!!.requestFocus()
            video_view!!.start()
```

Above code is working fine for me, but the issues I am facing are:

1. After few minutes the video is getting stuck in video view.
2. and sometimes it is showing "can not play this video", after playing the video for few minutes.

Comment: Try [Exoplayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer)

Comment: I have tried exoplayer also, but in exoplayer also some time I am getting the same result. and I have observed that campre to video view exoplayer is loading video slowly.

Comment: Does the live streaming video has higher resolution as compare to device support?

Comment: No, its less than the device resolution.

Comment: Try [GiraffePlayer2](https://github.com/tcking/GiraffePlayer2)